# Can't change to the specific scenes using UI buttons in unity, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, to start, I have this code:

```cs
public void switcher(string scene_name)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(scene_name, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
```

That's supposed to load a scene given in the editor, and I have 2 buttons, each supposed to load a specific scene and 2 gameobjects (one for scene) that  have the code written before.

[Object with script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHjL8.png)

[Button that calls object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7X6d.png)

Now, the thing is, despite having different scene names, both buttons load the same scene, and when I do some changes (mainly deleting and re-adding components) then both buttons load another scene, but never one scene each.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

First of all to load your scene you must add it to the build settings.Go to File>Build settings and then drag your scene into the Scenes in build.Sencond thing you must add this line of code to set you scene to be the active one
`SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + *Add you scene number here*);`

Comment: Already have the scenes in the build setting

Changed the code from what you gave me and still doesn't work